# Move up mobile menu without affecting the desktop side of things?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks for coming on here.

Anyways, on my website (http://www.wahneeevents.com/) The mobile menu is far beneath the navbar, which is a pain in the ass!

How can I go about making margin-top: -x px; on the collapse menu without disturbing my desktop side?

Thanks a ton - play around with the code in chrome by hitting f12.

Here's the problem we're having here.
[Website issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r8YJ.png)

```
    @media (min-width:768px){.navbar-left{float:left!important}.navbar-right{
    float: right!important;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}.navbar-right~.navbar-right{
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
}}.navbar-default{background-color:#f8f8f8;border-color:#e7e7e7}.navbar-default .navbar-brand{color:#777}.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover{color:#5e5e5e;background-color:transparent}.navbar-default .navbar-text{color:#777}.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{color:#777}.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{color:#333;background-color:transparent}.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover{color:#555;background-color:#e7e7e7}.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.disabled>a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:hover{color:#ccc;background-color:transparent}.navbar-default .navbar-toggle{border-color:#ddd}.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{background-color:#ddd}.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{background-color:#888}.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,.navbar-default .navbar-form{border-color:#e7e7e7}.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover{color:#555;background-color:#e7e7e7}@media (max-width:767px){.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a{color:#777}.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{color:#333;background-color:transparent}.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover{color:#555;background-color:#e7e7e7}.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:hover{color:#ccc;background-color:transparent}}.navbar-default .navbar-link{color:#633f1f}.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover{color:#333}.navbar-default .btn-link{color:#777}.navbar-default .btn-link:focus,.navbar-default .btn-link:hover{color:#333}.navbar-default .btn-link[disabled]:focus,.navbar-default .btn-link[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .navbar-default .btn-link:focus,fieldset[disabled] .navbar-default .btn-link:hover{color:#ccc}.navbar-inverse{
    background-color: #e0dfcd;
    border-color: #080808;
    height: 100px;
}.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand{color:#9d9d9d}.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover{color:#fff;background-color:transparent}.navbar-inverse .navbar-text{
    color: #633f1f;
    padding-left: 613px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a{color:#5B4100}.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
    color: #B98D45;
    background-color: #FFFFFF
}.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover{color:#fff;background-color:#080808}.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.disabled>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:hover{color:#444;background-color:transparent}.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle{border-color:#333}.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover{background-color:#333}.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{background-color:#fff}.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,.navbar-inverse .navbar-form{
    /* [disabled]border-color:#101010; */
}.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #633F1F
}
```

Comment: Use css media queries to give size-specific styling

Comment: I tried that without luck.

Comment: Can you post your css?

Comment: Sure, here you go!

Comment: Hard to read the indentation is off, but I don't see where you setting rule for mobile. `@media (min-width:768px)` is medium size and up.

Comment: Try using the media query and setting the top margin of`#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` to `0px`.  Then set `.navbar-nav` to have `margin-top: 19px;`.  This will have to be done in the media query for when the nav is collapsed as it will screw with the full sized style.